# Typescript adds plain export statement

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am building some typescript/react console app for Node.js.

If there is any import module in the source code it adds the `export {};` into the output.

**How I can get rid of the stuff please?**

I use

- typescript 4.1.2
- ts-node
- tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext",
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
    ]
}
```

Source code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
console.log("aaa");
```

Output:

```
console.log("aaa");
export {}; // <------ the problem
```

Fun fact: *when I remove the import, the export disappear.*

Comment: I believe this is because any file that includes an import or export is considered a *module* not just a script (in both ES2015+ and TS). And once transpiled, it stays a module, so the `export {};` is added to ensure it's still a module, not a script, in JavaScript's eyes. I may be wrong on the latter part though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of modules in ECMAScript 2015, ECMAScript has been split into two slightly incompatible languages: Scripts and Modules. However, there is no way to *explicitly* mark a resource as either a Script or a Module in-band. The only way to do that is out-of-band, e.g. via HTTP Content-Types or a command line flag that explicitly tells the ECMAScript engine to interpret the file as a Module.

So, in order to make it clear to the ECMAScript execution engine, that this is, in fact, a Module not a Script, the only way is to make sure that the resource can only legally interpreted as a Module and not a Script.

An empty `export` statement serves that purpose, since it is illegal in Scripts but has no side-effects.

Long story short: you *cannot* remove the `export` statement, because that will make the file ambiguous: it is impossible to tell from the source code alone whether the file is a Script or a Module. And for reasons of backwards-compatibility, most ECMAScript engines interpret ambiguous resources as Scripts. (A more strict engine might reject the file altogether, which is also not what you want.)

So, if you remove the `export` statement, your file will no longer be interpreted as a Module. However, the TypeScript source file *is* a Module (because it contains an `import` statement), therefore the compiler *must* emit the `export` statement in order to ensure that the *compiled* file is also a Module.

Answer (score 1):

From [this issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41562#issuecomment-729522609), if you are importing it just for typing, use `type` declaration instead:

```
type Foo = import("./Foo.js").Foo;

const foo: Foo = {
    fooValue: 0,
};
```

I found this out while making a Chrome Extension with a Content Script where it cannot be a module but TypeScript keeps adding empty `export {}` statement to the end of the file.